# Перевод из nginx в .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, nginx

Нужно прописать правило в htaccess, которое заменяет определённый файл .js на .php. Я пытался прописать как-то так

```
RewriteRule ^/js/index.php/x.js  ^.*\.php
```

Но это не работает. Есть готовое решение, но для nginx

```
location = /js/index.php/x.js { rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last; }
```

Comment: Вангую, что это понадобилось, чтобы [в каком-то определённом каталоге выполнять PHP внутри JS-скрипта](https://habrahabr.ru/post/139154/) и автор на самом деле хочет `AddHandler x-httpd-php .js`

Comment: @AK нет( у меня просто в запросе, в недере стоит X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff и читает мой JS как text и не может выполнить.